# How to check if a static library is built for 64-bit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries, lipo

I just built a static library for iOS with the build setting for Architectures set to `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT)`.

I want to make sure that the .a library is properly including that architecture, but when i run `lipo -info` on it, I see:

> Architectures in the fat file: library.a are: armv7 armv7s
>   (cputype (16777228) cpusubtype (0))

Does this mean that arm64 isn't included? If the lipo command can't tell me, is there another way to tell?

I'm running Xcode 5 with the latest Command Line Tools installed.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Yes, an arm64 slice is there.  To see it, you need to use `lipo` from the iOS toolchain, not from the host system (which doesn’t know about arm64):

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info $(FILENAME)
```

Comment: I'm curious about the difference between /usr/bin/lipo and xcrun's lipo. It seems like they are not one and the same.

Comment: @pshah It would appear, based on Stephen's answer, that the /usr/bin/lipo is the Mac's version of Lipo, while xcrun's lipo is XCode's lipo. So updating to XCode 5 meant getting a new lipo through xcrun.

Comment: Presumably because the one came out after the other, the `lipo` that ships with v10.9 appears to recognise arm64 natively. No need to invoke anything from Xcode. Running simply `lipo -info $(FILENAME)` reported `arm64` amongst others for a relevant library for me when tested.

Comment: On my machine, running macOS High Sierra, the lipos are both one and the same.

Comment: @saagarjha Yes, the default toolchain `lipo` now knows about all the supported architectures; this was not the case when arm64 was new.

Answer (score 69):

good old `file` can do the trick, too:

```
$ file libTestFlight.a

libTestFlight.a: Mach-O universal binary with 5 architectures
libTestFlight.a (for architecture armv7):   current ar archive random library
libTestFlight.a (for architecture armv7s):  current ar archive random library
libTestFlight.a (for architecture i386):    current ar archive random library
libTestFlight.a (for architecture x86_64):  current ar archive random library
libTestFlight.a (for architecture cputype (16777228) cpusubtype (0)):   current ar archive random library
```

It seems that nobody at Apple cared to add the arm64 cputype to `file`, yet.

Interestingly, in the iOS 7 Tech Talk Videos ("Architecting Modern Apps, Part 2", PDF page 35) they show a working file tool's output:

[image]

Comment: which OS version are you on? I'm on 10.9.1, and 'file' only lists the cputype instead of arm64.

Comment: I don't see an arm64 in your example output, which was what I was having trouble seeing

Comment: really cool and quick tool to check for supported file architectures

Comment: `file` did not work in my case, it just said `current ar archive random library`. Using `lipo -info` did work.

Answer (score 19):

For a `.framework`

`lipo -info myFramework.framework/MyFramework`

Comment: How does it show is lib static or dynamic?
My output:
```Architectures in the fat file: MyFramework are: arm64 x86_64```
for both types.