# Error while working on simulator, but works fine when running on device

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I am working on a project in which i imported external libraries but i endup with 169 erros when i run on simulator but this works perfect when i connect my iphone and build for it.

[image: this]

This is the screenshot of few errors i see in my xcode, I saw few questions here where they asked to change Architectures settings in Build setting

this is screenshot of my architecture setting

[image: xcode architecture screenshot]

As i am not able to run app on simulator due to this issues inspite trying various solutions on stack i still this many errors.

Please guide me.

Thank You

Comment: Clear Derived data folder and try.

Comment: It is the problem with the library. It is built only for the `Device Specific Arch`. Check this link for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992840/how-to-check-if-a-static-library-is-built-for-64-bit second answer.

Comment: @New16 I saw few of my framework shows (armv7, armv7s, arm64) and some showing (i386, x86_64, armv7, armv7s, arm64), So how can i fix this to run in simulator.

Comment: You can't fix this, whoever built the framework should have done this. Check with them to get the proper framework.

Comment: @New16 you sure about this, that there is no other way that i can atleast make my app work in simulator ignoring (without removing them)  the libraries which is causing trouble

Comment: Yeah, since you depend on those libs, your source code will contain those symbols. Create a new target to remove the source files where you use these symbols and remove those libs in this target.

Comment: @New16 Do you mean, that in a new git branch i remove this problem causing library and also its reference in my code?

Comment: Not in the git. XCode targets check this link https://www.raywenderlich.com/3716/unit-testing-tutorial-for-ios-xcode-4-quick-start-guide/ghunitsetup_006.

Comment: @New16 i will check this, but here how will i be able to do this as you mentioned in previous comment  

"to remove the source files where you use these symbols and remove those libs in this target."

Comment: You don't have to remove it manually. Just don't add those source files in build phases and don't add those frameworks to this particular target.