# Compile Ghostscript for iOS 11

Tags: ios, arm, ghostscript

I am attempting to compile Ghostscript (ver. 9-22) for iOS 11 to replace an older, 32-bit version of the library that was build for iOS 9 and before. Following the instructions found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190905185611/http://www.labs.saachitech.com/2014/03/16/ghostscript-ios-static-library/), I altered the final step in order to give me an arm64 dynamic library:

```
ar -crs libgs_arm64_release.a obj/*.o
```

However, if I do a:

```
lipo -info libgs_arm64_release.a
```

it tells me that:

```
input file libgs_arm64_release.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: libgs_arm64_release.a is architecture: x86_64
```

Thinking I was using the wrong tool, I also tried looking at using the lipo from the XCode toolchain per: [How to check if a static library is built for 64-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992840/how-to-check-if-a-static-library-is-built-for-64-bit/21261695) but got the same result that is believes it is an x86_64.

Thoughts on what step I am missing to compile for an arm64 architecture?

Answer (score 0):

> I altered the final step in order to give me an arm64 dynamic library:
>
> ```
> ar -crs libgs_arm64_release.a obj/*.o
> ```

`ar` is just the archive tool, that builds a library from the compiled object files. If you want an ARM library you have to specify this in the *compile* step via some switch like `-arch armv7`.

Are you sure you used the correct Makefile? The projects seems to have one for the Simulator (which is x86) and for the actual devices (ARM).

Comment: Yes, that is later to create a fat binary by bringing multiple architectures together.  Right now, I am just attempting to create the correct *.a file.  In regards to comment about the compile step, the ./configure looks like: ./configure CC="gcc -arch arm64" --disable-cups --disable-sse2

Comment: I was looking at the instructions found here: https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.22/Make.htm#Mac_build on building Ghostscript for the Mac OSX.

Comment: Just a warning here. As far as I'm aware, the Apple Store policies make it impossible to create an App which is AGPL. Obviously if this is a personal project then that's not a problem. But you can't use GPL Ghostscript for an app in the App Store.

Comment: @Perry: sorry, ignore my answer, it should have been a comment since it was just a guess.

Comment: This is an internal, business app that has licensed Ghostscript.