# bad CPU type in executable error from the CLI Provider Perspective

Tags: macos, command-line-interface, apple-m1, fat

I've my own open-source [CLI tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) called [surmagic](https://github.com/gurhub/surmagic). In my latest update, I've built on a different machine, which has an **M1 CPU**. Before and after publishing I've tested on that machine, via installing the [homebrew](https://brew.sh). And it works as expected. After a while, I've tested on another machine that has an **Intel CPU**. And, I've been faced with this error:

```
> surmagic --version
zsh: bad CPU type in executable: surmagic
```

I know what this error means from other libraries that I've used before, but the problem is how to solve this error as a CLI tool provider is another question.

I need help with this. How to solve this forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

First, check your Mac's architecture via the command below:

```
> arch
i386
```

if your result is **i386** like in my case. Then check the application binary's architecture via the command below:

```
> cd /usr/local/bin
> lipo -info surmagic
Non-fat file: surmagic is architecture: arm64
```

if this result is **[arm64 non-fat](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/pull/2787)**, like in my case, then you need to build a **FAT executable for your library**.

#### Follow the steps below:

## How to Build a Universal Binary

Firstly, make sure that you are using the correct version of Xcode/Swift:

```
> xcrun swift build --version
Swift Package Manager - Swift 5.5.0
```

*Note: If this is not Swift 5.3 or greater, use xcode-select -s to switch to the Xcode 12 beta.*

Now, when compiling your package, specify both architectures to compile a Universal Binary (the real irony here is my CLI tool actually makes FAT libraries for Xcode project):

```
> xcrun swift build -c release --arch arm64 --arch x86_64
```

To verify that your built binary contains both architectures, you can use the [lipo -info command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992840/how-to-check-if-a-static-library-is-built-for-64-bit) to inspect a binary and confirm:

```
> lipo -info .build/apple/Products/Release/surmagic
Architectures in the fat file: .build/apple/Products/Release/surmagic are: x86_64 arm64
```

If successful, you should see both `x86_64` and `arm64`.